# Fetch the Ubuntu USN from a script

Tags: python, security, beautifulsoup, urllib2

While doing Penetration Tests, it could be useful to consult security bugs grouped by distribution versions. More specifically, I would like to fetch [Ubuntu Security Notices](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/) from a python script.

My idea was to use urllib2 to fetch the data and BeautifulSoup to clean up the results.

Does anybody think of a cleaner way to achieve this result?

** UPDATE **

As pointed out by Omnikrys and John Mee, Atom and RSS are more easy format to work with, but AFAIK they only refer to newer distros, while I need a broader database.

Comment: Why not use one of the feeds? (RSS/Atom)

Answer (score 1):

No. You're on the right track. Although its probably easiest to parse the **for-program-consumption** [RSS](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/rss.xml) (or [Atom](http://www.ubuntu.com/usn/atom.xml)) feed than deconstruct a **for-human-consumption** webpage with soup.

Comment: RSS and Atom could be a good solution for "fresh" bugs. AFAIK, you can't fetch security notes for old releases, like Warty.